# Effective use of Array field in Mongo Collection

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, indexing

We are using Mongo DB in our application and in our collection we are storing array as field. eg:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ef67573848ec32b156b053"),
    "articleId" : "46384262",
    "host" : "example.com",
    "url" : "http://example.com/articleshow/46384262.cms",
    "publishTime" : NumberLong("1424954100000"),
    "tags" : [
            "wind power",
            "mytrah",
            "make in india",
            "government",
            "andhra pradesh"
    ],
    "catIds" : [
            "2147477890",
            "13352306",
            "13358350",
            "13358361"
    ]
}
```

Now my situation is need to create index on tags and catIds array as they are search field.
But creating an index on array field increases the size of indexes tremendously.
Could you please suggest a better way of achiving this.

Comment: This is not a solution but I think maybe you would be interested in MongoDB 3.0 which is currently in its `RC11` state. With new storage engine [WiredTiger](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/release-notes/3.0/#wiredtiger-concurrency-and-compression) indexes can by compressed (with the trade-off of CPU consumption).

Comment: @yaoxing I am waiting for their production release no Date is announced till now so need working on other solutions if that can help

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure your collection in this way. Now you will have 3 collections:

Coll1, documents look like this:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("54ef67573848ec32b156b053"),
   "articleId" : "46384262",
   ... your other stuff
}
```

Tags, documents look like this:

```
{
      '_id': 1,
      'name': 'wind power'
   }
   {
      '_id': 2,
      'name': 'mytrash'
   }
   ....
```

and a collection that links coll1 to tags:

```
{
   "collID" : ObjectId("54ef67573848ec32b156b053"),
   "tagID": 1
}
{
   "collID" : ObjectId("54ef67573848ec32b156b053"),
   "tagID": 2
}
```

Mongo does not have joins, so you need to do joins on the application layer. And it will take you 3 mongo queries. The size of indexes should be smaller, but test it before making significant changes.

Comment: These are not always numbers they can be string too this why i am using them as string

Comment: @viren got it. Anyway my answer has a possible solution for your problem.